# R 3.5.1 shiny dashboard theme change

Tags: css, r, shinydashboard

I want to connect external css file for R shiny dashboard. I am using R 3.5.1. I have downloaded cerulean theme as bootstrap.css in www directory. Using the code below

```
dashboardBody( 
   tags$head( 
       tags$link( rel="stylesheet",
                  type='text/css',
                  href = 'bootstrap.css'))
```

But cerulean theme is not appearing in shiny app.

Also I want to change the search input box displaying in 3D to 2D. Please have a look below:

[image]

New search input box should appear like below

[image]

Comment: For your search button, can you tell which function you are using to create it? It will come down to CSS styling the button (removing shading / borders), addressing the id/class of the button

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the following works, but from experience: just renaming the .css file in your www folder and, ofcourse, in the .R file gets it working.
Your code seems fine.

Alternatively you may try `includeCSS()`. For this you should put your CSS in your app directory.

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    includeCSS("styles.css"),
    ...
```